# Mac Mini A1347 - Oct 2012 , 64 Bit question

Tags: mac

I have a mac mini a1347  (Oct 2012 ) model. In the spec it says "64-bit enabled". What does 64-bit enabled mean?

Answer (score 0):

it means you have a 64 bit mac, for example you have 8gb RAM, you will need a 64 bit OS for your RAM to work properly, unlike 32 bit where that only supports 4gb RAM and lower. so i have to say that you have a good computer to be 64 bit.

Comment: Maximim supported RAM: Ubuntu 32-bit - 4GB RAM, Ubuntu 32-bit + PAE (Physical Address Extension) - 64GB RAM, PAE is now the standard for 32-bit Ubuntu, so there is no need for enabling it.

Comment: yea thats what i mean,